# "influence of A TO the process" or "influence of A FOR the process"

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

If I have the following idea,

> The influence of A, B and C ***to*** the reconstruction process is
> discussed in next section.

I am not sure whether I used the correct preposition. I feel I should use "for" (instead of "to") after A,B and C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you're looking for is *on*.

> The influence of A, B and C ***on*** the reconstruction process is discussed in next section.

*Influence to* and *influence for* don't make any sense. *Influence over* is possible, but usually in other contexts. For example:

> As an alumni who donates a lot of money to the school, I have some influence over the school board.

*Influence over* usually means something similar to sway/convincing power; that is, "I can get them to listen to me, and they're more likely to accept my ideas than if it were someone else presenting them."

*Influence on* is usually used in cases where the influence is more direct, and that's what applies in your case. Another example:

> The influence of government spending on the national debt is obvious.

When using *influence on*, you're usually describing something which *definitely* causes some factor (such as spending -> deficit, or your reconstruction example).